# vue3 Pan bugs when switching between d3.zoom and d3.brush

Tags: javascript, d3.js, vuejs3

I used vue3 and d3 to implement a multi-functional scatter plot.

[image: scatter plot]

- I used d3.brush() to select nodes
- I used d3.zoom() to pan and zoom
- I designed two buttons `pan` and `brush`: when we click one, enable the feature and disable anther.

  - As we know, zoom can be enabled in both. But pan and brush are conflict.
  - Specifically, I used `pinia` as a global store. And when the component `onMounted`, it saves function `brushEnableFunc` and `panEnableFunc` to `UIStore`. So buttons can bind to the 2 functions.
- Specially, I used css `resize` on the svg container box to make my plot resizable.

  - I used `watch` to listen to the changes of width and height, and recalculate the coordinates.

When I switch between brush and pan, it works well.

However, after I resize the container, the brush and zoom behavior still works, but the pan has bugs:

Sometimes, I can't drag in pan mode. Sometimes, in brush mode, brush and pan works together (even if mouse are hovered, not clicked, svg is still panning and dragging).

What should I do to fix the bugs? Or is there some ways to decouple the code?

Some related codes:

Brush and zoom are reactive to width and height.

```js
const brush = computed(() =>
    d3
        .brush()
        .on("start", brushStart)
        .on("end", brushEnd)
        .extent([
            [0, 0],
            [props.width, props.height],
        ])
);
```

```js
const zoom = computed(() =>
    d3
        .zoom()
        .extent([
            [0, 0],
            [props.width, props.height],
        ])
        .scaleExtent([1 / 2, 16])
        .translateExtent([
            [0, 0],
            [props.width, props.height],
        ])
);
```

On mounted lifecycle hook:

```js
onMounted(() => {
    const gBrush = d3.select(svgRef.value).append("g").attr("class", "gBrush");

    zoom.value.on("zoom", (event) => {
        transformRef.value = event.transform; // keep the transform value to apply to some coords value

        gBrush.attr("transform", event.transform);  //when we zoom, brush rect should also zoom
    });

    if (UIStore.isBrushEnabled) {   //at the first time, brush is enabled, or pan?

        zoom.value.filter((event) => event.type === "wheel"); // only zoom in and out
        gBrush.call(brush.value);
    } else {
        zoom.value.filter(
            (event) =>
                (!event.ctrlKey || event.type === "wheel") && !event.button //default
        );
    }


    //always bind zoom
    d3.select(svgRef.value).call(zoom.value);

    UIStore.brushEnableFunc = () => {
        const gBrush = d3.select(svgRef.value).select(".gBrush");
        zoom.value.filter((event) => event.type === "wheel");
       
        gBrush.style("display", "inherit"); // 
        gBrush.call(brush.value); //rebind
    };

    UIStore.panEnableFunc = () => {
        const gBrush = d3.select(svgRef.value).select(".gBrush");
        gBrush.style("display", "none"); // hide rect，

  
        zoom.value.filter(
            (event) =>
                (!event.ctrlKey || event.type === "wheel") && !event.button //default
        );
      
    };

}); // onMounted END
```

so button can be bound to:

```js
const handlePanClick = (e) => {
   
    UIStore.isBrushEnabled = false;
    UIStore.panEnableFunc(); 
};

const handleBrushClick = (e) => {
    
    UIStore.isBrushEnabled = true;
    UIStore.brushEnableFunc();
};
```

watch the changes of width and height (resized)

```js
watch(
    [() => props.width, () => props.height],
    ([newWidth, newHeight], [oldWidth, oldHeight]) => {
  
        const gBrush = d3.select(svgRef.value).select(".gBrush");
    

        points.value = rescaleCoords( // recalculate the coords
            points.value || [],
            props.width,
            props.height,
            (d) => d[0],
            (d) => d[1]
        );

        const rect = d3.brushSelection(gBrush.node()); //get the rect
        if (rect) {
                const [[x0, y0], [x1, y1]] = rect;
                gBrush.call(brush.value.move, (datum, i, node) => { // move the rect
                  
                    return [ [ (x0 * newWidth) / oldWidth, (y0 * newHeight) / oldHeight],
                        [(x1 * newWidth) / oldWidth, (y1 * newHeight) / oldHeight] ];
                });
        }
     

        gBrush.call(brush.value);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

emmm, the `zoom` is defined as `computed`, that's where the bugs hide.

I rewrite `zoom` with plain `d3.zoom()`, and dynamically change its extends in `watch`, then the plot works well.

But `brush` is also defined as `computed` and has no bugs.